# Cannot select fields with the mouse Windows 7

Tags: mouse

Lately I cannot select a word (field) with the mouse. When I left click on a field drag the mouse to the end of the field then release the button, the selection (blue shading) disappears. Sometimes after several tries the shading stays and I can delete the field. Up to a week ago everything worked fine. Is this a bug, virus? I am using Windows 7

Also, in Live Mail after I finished reading an item in the Inbox, I click the X in the upper right corner to return to the rest of my mail, but instead it takes me back to the desktop and have to double click the Live Mail again to continue. Again this only happened recently. Things worked OK before and this does not happen regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typical case of the mouse button failing to work properly, and registering spurious double-clicks when you meant to click once, or not being able to stay pressed while the drag is taking place.

Simplest solution is to replace the mouse.